# Creating a common REST API consumption module for Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

All,

I am looking for some pointers to create a common module for 10 of my PHP applications to use. All these 10 applications will need to consume third party rest apis. They don't need to create APIs, just consume only.

So, I have this code to consume a rest api. How do I go about creating a common REST API consumption module from this code, so I don't need to duplicate this code across all my php applications?

```
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Client;
use Zend\Stdlib\Parameters;

$request = new Request();
$request->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
    'Content-Type' = > 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
));
$request->setUri($someurl);
$request->setMethod('POST');
$request->setPost(new Parameters(array('someparam' = > $somevalue)));

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->dispatch($request);
$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would create a new module like you would in any ZF2 application, and the above code would live in a class inside of that module. In your other applications, you simply bring in the module as a dependency and extend or make calls to the class containing the code above.

I highly recommend  [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)  if you aren't using it to manage dependencies already.

Comment: So, what you are saying is, I don't need any controllers or views in this new common module, but just have a class in the model directory of the module. Right? I was wondering if I need to create a new PHP application with 1 module in it and have that class in that module

Comment: Correct. Your module's top level folder would contain your config folder with your module.config file, and then your src folder with your code/classes inside of it. No need for controllers/views etc. This github repo I found has a similar structure to what you are aiming for I believe. https://github.com/neeckeloo/Crocodoc

Comment: I see.. This is a little off-topic.. Can I create a PHP application called "common" and have 2 or 3 modules in them with classes like you mentioned and somehow use dependency manager to use these modules and reference them in my other PHP projects?

Comment: Traditionally, you would just bring in the modules individually. However, if you are using all of them all the time, perhaps you should consolidate them into a single module named Common?